# Incorrect return value, not getting a 'True' return, Python

Tags: python, return-value, palindrome

I am expecting a return of True, but is getting a return of None.

I have put some print statement in the code to help debug. It shows that the 'print("Got True")' statement ran, so I know the code ended up in the right branch of the code just before 'return True' but for some reason I am getting 'None'. However 'return False' works perfectly when I put in a word that isn't a palindrome.

Thanks for the help.

```
def first(word):
    return word[0]

def last(word):
    return word[-1]

def middle(word):
    return word[1:-1]

def is_palindrome(word):
    print(word)
    if len(word) <= 1:
        print("Got True")
        return True
    else:
        print(len(word))
        if first(word) == last(word):
            is_palindrome(middle(word))
        else:
            print("Got False")
            return False

print(is_palindrome('allen'))
print("\n")
print(is_palindrome('redivider'))
```

Output:

```
allen
5
Got False
False


redivider
9
edivide
7
divid
5
ivi
3
v
Got True
None
```

Comment: If you don't return anything, the return value will be `None`. And in some cases, you don't return anything, namely here: `is_palindrome(middle(word))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return in every branch of your function, e.g.:

```
def is_palindrome(word):
    print(word)
    if len(word) <= 1:
        print("Got True")
        return True
    else:
        print(len(word))
        if first(word) == last(word):
            return is_palindrome(middle(word))  # **Added return**
        else:
            print("Got False")
            return False
```

But you can simplify the structure because if you `return` then you don't need the `else:` clause because it can't be reached, so this can be written:

```
def is_palindrome(word):
    print(word)
    if len(word) <= 1:
        print("Got True")
        return True

    print(len(word))
    if first(word) == last(word):
        return is_palindrome(middle(word))

    print("Got False")
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

Even in a recursive function, you have to use a return statement to return a value:

```
   if first(word) == last(word):
        return is_palindrome(middle(word))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return the result in every possible conditional branches. You can use directly return statement or capture the result of the is_palindrome function in some variable and return that if it is confusing.